# Adding missing date records in the time series data table, for each ID subgroup

Tags: mysql

I am working with a table which has data for weekdays. The data is pretty much about daily end of the day balance. The data looks like this:

```
ID  Name        Some Val    Other Val   Date

10  Somebody    33001.93    33001.93    2018-10-01
10  Somebody    33481.93    33481.93    2018-10-02
10  Somebody    33001.93    33001.93    2018-10-03
10  Somebody    33582.76    33582.76    2018-10-04
10  Somebody    33582.73    33582.79    2018-10-05
------- Missing row for 2018-10-06 ---------------
------- Missing row for 2018-10-07 ---------------
10  Somebody    33582.76    33582.76    2018-10-08
------- Missing row for 2018-10-09 ---------------
10  Somebody    33462.76    33462.76    2018-10-10
```

My task is to calculate average daily balance (total balance at end of each day/ total number of days). To get to that calculation, I need to ensure that I've data for all the days. To do that, the last available row needs to replace the missing data.

My need is this:

```
ID  Name        Some Val    Other Val   Date

10  Somebody    33001.93    33001.93    2018-10-01
10  Somebody    33481.93    33481.93    2018-10-02
10  Somebody    33001.93    33001.93    2018-10-03
10  Somebody    33582.76    33582.76    2018-10-04
10  Somebody    33582.73    33582.79    2018-10-05    
10  Somebody    33582.73    33582.79    2018-10-06
10  Somebody    33582.73    33582.79    2018-10-07    
10  Somebody    33582.76    33582.76    2018-10-08
10  Somebody    33382.76    33582.76    2018-10-09
10  Somebody    33462.76    33462.76    2018-10-10
```

Essentially, the row 5 is written into missing rows 6 and 7 and row 8 gets written into row 9.

I got the solution working by creating a calendar table and then using the following query:

```
SELECT  
CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN (SELECT ID 
                        FROM T tt 
                        WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                        ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                        LIMIT 1)  
ELSE ID END ID,
CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN (SELECT Name 
                        FROM T tt 
                        WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                        ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                        LIMIT 1) 
ELSE Name END Name,
CASE WHEN SomeVal IS NULL THEN (SELECT SomeVal 
                        FROM T tt 
                        WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                        ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                        LIMIT 1) 
ELSE SomeVal END SomeVal,
CASE WHEN OtherVal IS NULL THEN (SELECT OtherVal 
                        FROM T tt 
                        WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                        ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                        LIMIT 1) 
ELSE OtherVal END OtherVal,
minDt
FROM calendar t1 
LEFT JOIN T t2 ON t1.minDt = t2.Date
ORDER BY t1.minDT;
```

This solution worked when the ID value was constant. I realized that my dataset has thousands of records with few hundred unique id values. Each id can have missing values. The above query replaces just top of the data, not the entire data. I need to run the same query for each id. I guess partition by works in mysql but I am not quite sure how to try it.

The data actually looks something like this:

```
10,'Somebody',33001.93,33001.93,'2018-10-01'
10,'Somebody',33481.93,33481.93,'2018-10-02'
10,'Somebody',33001.93,33001.93,'2018-10-03'
10,'Somebody',33582.76,33582.76,'2018-10-04'
10,'Somebody',33582.73,33582.79,'2018-10-05'
10,'Somebody',33582.76,33582.76,'2018-10-08'
15,'someone else',33462.76,33462.76,'2018-10-1'
15,'someone else',33582.76,33582.76,'2018-10-04'
15,'someone else',33582.73,33582.79,'2018-10-05'
15,'someone else',33582.76,33582.76,'2018-10-08'
15,'someone else',33462.76,33462.76,'2018-10-10'
```

Here is where you can try out with the dummy data and above query:

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eSvCvD6gzB8RPBERZRwcjd/0)

The MySQL version I am using is:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: @d-shih - Seeking your help/recommendation here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL variables to fill out your table data. The trick is to `JOIN` the calendar table to a list of distinct `ID` values from your table so as to get a table which has an ID and date for each date in the range. This can then be `LEFT JOIN`ed to the data table to get values where they exists, and MySQL variables can be used to fill in the gaps:

```
SELECT thedate,
       @name := coalesce(Name, @name) AS Name,
       @someval := coalesce(SomeVal, @someval) AS SomeVal,
       @otherval := coalesce(OtherVal, @otherval) AS OtherVal,
       @id := id AS id
FROM (SELECT c.thedate, i.id, t.Name, t.SomeVal, t.OtherVal
      FROM calendar c
      JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t) i
      LEFT JOIN t ON t.date = c.thedate AND t.id = i.id) g
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @id := 0, @name := '', @someval := 0, @otherval := 0) v
ORDER BY id, thedate
```

Output for your sample data:

```
thedate     Name            SomeVal     OtherVal    id
2018-10-01  Somebody        33001.93    33001.93    10
2018-10-02  Somebody        33481.93    33481.93    10
2018-10-03  Somebody        33001.93    33001.93    10
2018-10-04  Somebody        33582.76    33582.76    10
2018-10-05  Somebody        33582.73    33582.79    10
2018-10-06  Somebody        33582.73    33582.79    10
2018-10-07  Somebody        33582.73    33582.79    10
2018-10-08  Somebody        33582.76    33582.76    10
2018-10-09  Somebody        33582.76    33582.76    10
2018-10-10  Somebody        33582.76    33582.76    10
2018-10-01  someone else    33462.76    33462.76    15
2018-10-02  someone else    33462.76    33462.76    15
2018-10-03  someone else    33462.76    33462.76    15
2018-10-04  someone else    33582.76    33582.76    15
2018-10-05  someone else    33582.73    33582.79    15
2018-10-06  someone else    33582.73    33582.79    15
2018-10-07  someone else    33582.73    33582.79    15
2018-10-08  someone else    33582.76    33582.76    15
2018-10-09  someone else    33582.76    33582.76    15
2018-10-10  someone else    33462.76    33462.76    15
```

I've created a demo on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=909aa89ba08f33643e47e22eaa22c6e5) which shows how all the pieces go together (including my calendar table, which only includes the dates from your table).

Comment: Looks neat. I am new to SQL and trying the understand the logic.

Comment: @SushantVasishta I have tested it on my MySQL 5.6 server as well and it works fine.

Comment: Yupp. Workd great. Have marked your solution as the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I got some headway by utilizing the same logic as mentioned above. Had to create the calendar lookup table with id data. And I am matching at date and id level. The resultant table gets a lot of duplicate/empty records but dedpuing the data pretty much gives me what I need.

This certainly isn't the most elegant solution since the temp datasets that I am using are pretty big. There must a more concise solution but for the moment this worked for me.